# How does a theory give rise to a category with finite products?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, lo.logic

In the paper *Diagonal Arguments and Cartesian Closed Categories* ([here](http://tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/15/tr15abs.html)), Lawvere presents a fixed-point theorem that generalizes both Cantor's theorem and Gödel's (first) Incompleteness Theorem.

In order to accomplish this, Lawvere sketches *briefly* how a theory gives rise to a category $C$ with finite products.[image]

The description goes on by declaring substitution as the correspondent composition and mentioning other properties.

At first, my question was a *reference request* where the **explicit** category above is discussed *less briefly*, i.e., with more attention to the details.

However, since such a reference seems hard to find, I would like to ask (alternatively) for an explanation about how this category works. This is very vague, to say the least, so let me emphasize some major points:

1. why the objects have the *form* $A^n\times 2^m$?
2. what are the projections $A^n\times 2^m\to 2^m$ and $A^n\times 2^m\to A^n$?
3. what is an arrow $A^3\to A^2$?
4. what is an arrow $2^4\to 2^3$?

Although the list above does not explain the category $C$, I believe that if I understand these points then I will be able to do the rest.

Comment: Lawvere’s thesis is one possible place to start.

Comment: I'll check there, thank you.

Comment: These are known as [Lawvere theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory). The book [Algebraic theories](https://perso.uclouvain.be/enrico.vitale/gab_CUP2.pdf) is a good introduction (Chapter 11 specifically covers the concept Lawvere mentions here) and [The Category Theoretic Understanding of Universal Algebra](https://www.irif.fr/~mellies/mpri/mpri-ens/articles/hyland-power-lawvere-theories-and-monads.pdf) is a nice survey paper. Lawvere's thesis is not a particularly accessible starting point.

Comment: I'll check these too. Thank you.

Comment: Although the suggested references are nice, it seems they do not address the category defined in the article: they deal with the general context (Lawvere theories) in which the category $C$ fits... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: could you elaborate? It seems to me that the category $\mathbf C$ Lawvere is defining in the paper mentioned is a 2-sorted Lawvere theory (with the sorts being $A$ and $2$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber: the morphisms of a Lawvere theory are entirely abstract. Lawvere is taking the morphisms $X \to 2$ to be predicates in a first-order logic, but their semantic intent is entirely opaque to the cartesian category. You could take the morphisms to be whatever you wanted.

Comment: The whole thing has a bit of a Lindenbaum algebra feel to it.

Comment: @AsafKaragila it does, indeed. It is like the arrows are the equivalence classes of the Lindenbaum algebra, while the objects are theses artificial $A$ and $2$. But it still feels _ineffable_ to me...

Comment: 1. The objects have that form because the category has finite products and is generated by $A$ and $2$. 2. The projections are the ones in the definition of binary products. 3. An arrow $A^3 \to A^2$ is a pair of of arrows $A^3 \to A$, i.e. a pair of (equivalence classes of) terms with 3 variables. 4. An arrow $2^4 \to 2^3$ is a triple of arrows $2^4 \to 2$, i.e. a triple of boolean functions with 4 variables.

Comment: Actually, there are more arrows $2^4 \to 2$ than just boolean functions – rather they are (equivalence classes of) predicates with 4 propositional variables. But you get the idea.

Comment: @ZhenLin "The projections are the ones in the definition of binary products". I think that this is my problem with this kind of description. See, obviously the projections of a product in any category have to satisfy the definition of binary products... My point is: with the definition of _what is an arrow in this category_, one should be able to understand which arrows do the job of projections. Am I wrong?

Comment: Anyway, the other points you made were really helpful. So thanks again. :)

Comment: I think Zhen is saying with $2$ that the projection is *literally* the projection from the binary product $A^n\times2^m$ into either its first factor $A^n$ or second factor $2^m$.

Comment: Okay... I need a drink (mind blowing right now).

Comment: "Lawvere presents a fixed-point theorem that generalizes both Cantor's theorem and Gödel's (first) Incompleteness Theorem." <--- Strictly speaking, the _contrapositive_ of Lawvere's fixed-point theorem is the generalisation of the other two.